# Cannot convert utf-8 in Stored Procedure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, utf-8

I'm stuck in the utf-8 format. I used CAST or CONVERT USING UTF-8. Even I set character N in front of query string but it's still not working.

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPC_SP_HSDXTChinh_BangSo4_Fake]
    @idDuAn NUMERIC(18, 0),
    @idGoiThau NUMERIC(18, 0),
    @idDonVi INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @resultString NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @queryString NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @Str_TinhHopLe NVARCHAR(255), @Str_DanhGia NVARCHAR(255), @Str_XepHang NVARCHAR(255);
    SET @Str_TinhHopLe = 'N''Kết quả đánh giá tính hợp lệ của HSĐXTC''';
    SET @Str_DanhGia = 'N''Giá đánh giá''';
    SET @Str_XepHang = 'N''Xếp hạng các HSDT''';

    SELECT @resultString = COALESCE(@resultString + ',', '') + RES.TenNhaThau
    FROM (
        SELECT '[' + TenNhaThau + ']' AS TenNhaThau
        FROM [SPC_fn_HSDXTChinh_NhaThau_CoTinhHopLe] (@idDuAn, @idGoiThau, @idDonVi)
    ) RES
    --PRINT @resultString
    PRINT @Str_TinhHopLe;
    SET @queryString = '
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS STT,' + @Str_TinhHopLe + '  AS NoiDung,
            CAST(RES.TenNhaThau AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS TenNhaThau, 
            CAST(RES.KetQuaDanhGia AS VARCHAR(25)) AS KetQuaDanhGia
        FROM [SPC_fn_HSDXKThuat_BangSo4] (' + CAST(@idDuAn AS VARCHAR(20)) + ',' + CAST(@idGoiThau AS VARCHAR(20)) + ',' + CAST(@idDonVi AS VARCHAR(10)) + ') RES
        ) SRC
    PIVOT(MAX(KetQuaDanhGia) FOR TenNhaThau IN (' + @resultString + ')) P 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 2 AS STT
            ,' + @Str_DanhGia + ' AS NoiDung,
                CAST(RES.TenNhaThau AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS TenNhaThau, 
                CAST(RES.GiaTri AS VARCHAR(25)) AS GiaTri 
            FROM [SPC_fn_HSDXKThuat_BangSo4] (' + CAST(@idDuAn AS VARCHAR(20)) + ',' + CAST(@idGoiThau AS VARCHAR(20)) + ',' + CAST(@idDonVi AS VARCHAR(10)) + ') RES
        ) SRC2
    PIVOT(MAX(GiaTri) FOR TenNhaThau IN (' + @resultString + ')) P 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 3 AS STT
            ,' + @Str_XepHang + ' AS NoiDung,
                CAST(RES.TenNhaThau AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS TenNhaThau, 
                CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GiaTri) AS VARCHAR(25)) AS XepHang
            FROM [SPC_fn_HSDXKThuat_BangSo4] (' + CAST(@idDuAn AS VARCHAR(20)) + ',' + CAST(@idGoiThau AS VARCHAR(20)) + ',' + CAST(@idDonVi AS VARCHAR(10)) + ') RES
        ) SRC2
    PIVOT(MAX(XepHang) FOR TenNhaThau IN (' + @resultString + ')) P 
    ';
    PRINT @queryString;
    EXEC (@queryString);
END
```

A part of output messages after run stored:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS STT,
    N'K?t qu? dánh giá tính h?p l? c?a HSÐXTC' AS NoiDung,
    CAST(RES.TenNhaThau AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS TenNhaThau, 
    CAST(RES.KetQuaDanhGia AS VARCHAR(25)) AS KetQuaDanhGia
FROM 
    [SPC_fn_HSDXKThuat_BangSo4] (60006000000000166, 60006000000000347, 60006) RES
```

You can see error text: `N'K?t qu? dánh giá tính h?p l? c?a HSÐXTC'`.

I want to output: `Kết quả đánh giá tính hợp lệ của HSĐXTC`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh: I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: I advise, as well, that you declare all your literal strings as an `nvarchar`. When you are constructing your dynamic SQL you are using a `varchar`, not an `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines in your procedure:

```
SET @Str_TinhHopLe = N'Kết quả đánh giá tính hợp lệ của HSĐXTC';
SET @Str_DanhGia = N'Giá đánh giá';
SET @Str_XepHang = N''Xếp hạng các HSDT';
```

Comment: @Quan Le Duc Minh You found your answer or not??